# Why doesn't this factoring to order-finding reduction work?

Tags: factoring, quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptanalysis, shors-algorithm

Scott Aaronson likes to motivate the factoring-to-period-finding algorithm used inside Shor's algorithm as [follows](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=208).

> Now, I want you to step back and think about what this means. It means that, if we can find the period of the sequence
>
> $$x \bmod N,\quad x^2 \bmod N, \quad x^3 \bmod N, \quad x^4 \bmod N, \quad \dots $$
>
> then we can learn something about the prime factors of $N$! In particular, we can learn a divisor of $(p-1)(q-1)$. Now, I’ll admit that’s not as good as learning $p$ and $q$ themselves, but grant me that it’s something. Indeed, it’s more than something: it turns out that if we could learn several random divisors of $(p-1)(q-1)$ (for example, by trying different random values of $x$), then with high probability we could put those divisors together to learn $(p-1)(q-1)$ itself. And once we knew $(p-1)(q-1)$, we could then use some more little tricks to recover $p$ and $q$, the prime factors we wanted.

See also Section 19.2 (pp 156) of his [Lecture notes](https://www.scottaaronson.com/qclec.pdf) where he expounds upon on the same idea. However, in both expositions he ends with a dismissal of the idea:

> Unfortunately, this doesn’t quite  work  with  Shor’s  algorithm,  because  the  period  of $f \colon r \mapsto x^r \bmod N$ might  not  equal $\phi(N)$, the most we can say is that the period *divides* $\phi(N)$.

**But *why* doesn't it work?**

As Aaronson himself noted, by repeating the algorithm with different values of $x$ wouldn't there be a chance of finding all the factors of $\phi(N)$ (or at least sufficiently many to figure out the remaining factors somehow)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aaronson's notes discuss finding $p$ and $q$ if we know $\phi(N)$ by solving the quadratic equation $X^2-(N-\phi(N)+1)X+N=0$ whose roots are $p$ and $q$. This only works if $N$ is the product of two distinct primes (which is the case in most applications of interest) and if we know $\phi(N)$ exactly.

What doesn't often get mentioned about RSA and multiplicative orders is that although the multiplicative order divides $\phi(N)$, it is never equal to it. In fact it always divides the smaller quantity $\lambda(N)$, the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of $N$ and sometimes is equal to it. In the case of two distinct prime factors $p$ and $q$, $\lambda(N)=\mathrm{LCM}(p-1,q-1)$. Shor's algorithm has a pretty good chance of delivering $\lambda(N)$ and the LCM of multiple runs should give the exact value. One then knows (in the two prime case) that $\phi(N)=\mathrm{GCD}(p-1,q-1)\lambda(N)$ and might hope to exhaust over possible values of the GCD in order to use the quadratic equation.

People could start to build $p$ and $q$ to make this GCD large (which is not a good use of time) specifically to block the quadratic equation recovery. Instead we prefer to teach the ``[random square root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm#Obtaining_factors_from_period)'' recovery of the factors which only needs $\lambda(N)$, which works for moduli with more than 2 prime factors and is not effectively blocked by trying to choose $p$ and $q$ in strange ways.

ETA: On further reflection, rather than exhaust over possible values of $\mathrm{GCD}(p-1,q-1)$ on could take the GCD of $N-1$ and $\lambda(N)$ and mess around. This would probably lead to $\phi(N)$ in short order in the two prime case, but the details begin to get more involved than the square root of unity description.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the approach *can* technically work? (At least for the common RSA-case?). I created a short [Sage script](https://pastebin.com/iegQJ5L6) creating many random p and q around 1024 bit, and the factor between $\phi(N)$ and $\lambda(N)$ was seldom more than 100 (usually just 2, 4, 6, ...).

Comment: Yes, it can work in the two prime case, it's just that keeping track of the precise details makes the full argument lengthy. The square root of unity calculation is also essentially the same as [congruent squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_of_squares) methods and so is already familiar to people who have studied classical factoring methods. This may be another reason for the preference.

Answer (score 1):

I would have written a comment to extend on Daniel's answer — but since I am not usually on the stack exchange, I am seemingly not able to comment, and so I will write a follow-up answer instead:

Ideas similar to that those that you are alluding to are used in [[E21b]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11128-021-03069-1) to develop a classical post-processing algorithm that leverages ideas from [[Miller76]](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0000(76)80043-8) to completely factor any integer $N$ with very high probability of success in a single run of Shor's order-finding algorithm.

More specifically, let
\begin{align*}
  N = \prod_{i \, = \, 1}^{n} p_i^{e_i}
\end{align*}
for $\{ p_1, \ldots, p_n \}$ a set of $n \ge 2$ distinct odd primes, and $\{ e_1, \ldots, e_n \}$ a set of positive integer exponents.
It then suffices that we are able to construct a positive integer multiple of
\begin{align*}
  \mathrm{lcm}(p_1 - 1, \ldots, p_{s-1} - 1, p_{s+1} - 1, p_n - 1),
\end{align*}
for any choice of $s \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ (i.e. at most one $p_i - 1$ may be left out), for us to be able to factor $N$ completely. Such a multiple may be constructed efficiently, and with very high probability of success, if we are given the order $r$ of a single element $g$ selected uniformly at random from $\mathbb Z_N^*$.

The success probability is lower-bounded in [[E21b]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11128-021-03069-1): It is shown to be very large already for moderate $N$, and it can be made to tend to one asymptotically by picking parameters appropriately.

See also the [factoritall](https://github.com/ekera/factoritall) repository on GitHub for a reference implementation of the algorithm, along with an order-finding simulator that allows the algorithm to be tested.

Comment: Your welcome addition was too long for a comment anyway!